# Convert comma separated ArrayList value to String - Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the String values as

```
"one","two","three", "four",
```

But what I currently get is

```
"one","two","three, four",
```

Here's the code, I've a comma separated value in the ArrayList but I want to take that comma separated values as two distinct values and not as one.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three, four");

String listString = "";

for (String s : list)
{
    listString += "\"" + s + "\",";
}

System.out.println(listString);
```

Is it possible? If yes, how do I do that?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but **you** need to do the splitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the ArrayList won't automatically split on the comma. If you add "three, four" into an ArrayList, then a single entry with the value "three, four" will be added.

Therefore, you'll need to split "three, four" yourself - the split method returns an array:

```
String[] strings = "three, four".split(", ");
list.add(strings[0]);
list.add(strings[1]);
```

Bear in mind that the argument to the split method is a regular expression - it won't make any difference in this case, but it can be a gotcha in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate through the list, you can check if the string contains a comma and if it does, then split by ", " (using string.split(", ")) and then print out each string with the formatting that you want.

The ArrayList will not split your third entry. It just assumes it as a single string entry and hence you get the result you see.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it as expected:

```
   list.addAll(Arrays.asList("three, four".split(",")));
```

Answer (score 1):

In modern Java, you can use a stream and just split every element wether or not it has a comma in it instead of having to check each element of the list:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = List.of("one", "two", "three, four");
        Pattern comma = Pattern.compile(",\\s*");

        String joined = list.stream()
            .flatMap(s -> comma.splitAsStream(s)) // Split each element and concatenate all results                                                                                                                                              
            .map(s -> "\"" + s + "\"") // Add quotes around each element                                                                                                                                                              
            .collect(Collectors.joining(",")); // Join into a string separated by commas                                                                                                                                                         
        System.out.println(joined); // "one","two","three","four"                                                                                                                                                                                
    }
}
```